# Ayuda con SAP e integración con Java usando JCO

Tags: java, sap, jco

Hola necesito ayuda con una integracion de SAP con JAVA. Estamos usando la api de JCO y al recuperar la plantilla de una función me muestra lo siguiente.

```
Input:
IV_SIZE_EXCHG  
IV_TRGID  
Changing:
null
Output:
EV_TOTAL_ZDT1  
Tables:
ET_ARTICLES  
ET_LOCATION_KEYS
ET_TREAGERS  
IT_LOCATION_KEYS
RETURN  
Exceptions:
```

Mi cliente recupera datos filtrando por la tabla `IT_LOCATION_KEYS`, pero como podeis ver esa tabla está en la parte de salida y no la parte de entradas, así que cuando intento filtrar haciendo `import` me dice que no existe la tabla.

Por cierto, si alguien me puede decir si hay alguna forma de simular esta consulta en SAP

```
select top 10 from tabla
```

Sólo necesito recuperar algún dato pero no hay forma. Y filtrando por los 2 campos simples no sirve de nada.

Answer (score 1):

Debes verificar cuales parámetros son obligatorios de tu RFC y brindarlos.
Generalmente los parámetros `IMPORTING` de la RFC son los que aportan los filtros que dentro de la función se utilizarán para obtener los datos y estos los devuelve ya sea por `EXPORTING` o por parámetros `CHANGING` o `TABLES` aunque estos dos últimos pueden ser entradas también, por lo tanto debes de revisar bien las entradas que estás llenando.

```
SELECT * FROM tabla INTO TABLE tabla_interna UPTO 10 ROWS.
```